# PHP to GEOJSON array not looping rows in MYSQL database

Tags: php, arrays, geojson

My PHP file connects successfully to a MSQL database and queries all the columns in 3 tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM facilitator, address, certification WHERE certification.ID=10002 LIMIT 0,3";
```

I'm limiting the output to 3 rows for this example.

But my array is producing multiple sets of the same user's data. It appears not to be looping through the database's rows. Here's the PHP array

```
// Create array
$geojson = array('type' => 'FeatureCollection', 'features' => array());

// Loop each row in database
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $marker = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'properties' => array(
          'Name' => $row['First_Name'],
        ),
        'geometry' => array(
          'type' => 'Point',
          'coordinates' => array( 
            $row["Longitude"], $row["Latitude"]
          )
        )
      );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $marker);
}

$json_string = json_encode($geojson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "<pre>".$json_string."<pre/>";
```

And the GEOJSON results (limited to 3 users)

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "Name": "Luz"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                "175.298090",
                "-37.791458"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "Name": "Luz"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                "175.298090",
                "-37.791458"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "Name": "Luz"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                "175.298090",
                "-37.791458"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

You can see "Luz" data is repeated each time. Can you help me with where the array is incorrect please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So, the array is working correctly, but preceded by an incorrect SQL statement requiring suitable JOIN. Something like this provides a working combination,

```
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Name
FROM facilitator
INNER JOIN certification USING (Client_ID)
WHERE facilitator.Last_Name='Smith'
```

I should point out that the JSON file coordinates are wrapped in quotes " which produces a string and not a number required for maps.